# PL/SQL DDL Execute Immediate

Tags: plsql

```
ACCEPT p_username PROMPT 'Enter Username : '
ACCEPT p_password PROMPT 'Enter New Password for Username : '
VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(4000)
DECLARE
   CURSOR NAME IS SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES 
      WHERE OWNER LIKE '%&p_username%';
   DDL_DROP VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   FOR TNAME IN NAME
   LOOP
       BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE' || ' ' || TNAME.TABLE_NAME;
         :g_output := :g_output || ' ' || TNAME.TABLE_NAME;
       END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
PRINT g_output
```

Hello,  I'm new to PL/SQL and trying to make a script to drop the user's table and ultimately change their password later after dropping their tables.  I am having difficulty with the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command.  The script works if I remove the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE line.  I tested it by printing the table names inside the loop and I get the right # of tables and their corresponding names.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edited the code to reflect the suggestion but still didn't work.  Getting the same error.

```
ACCEPT p_username PROMPT 'Enter Username : '
ACCEPT p_password PROMPT 'Enter New Password for Username : '
VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(4000)
DECLARE
   NAME SYS_REFCURSOR;
   DDL_WORD VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   OPEN NAME FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES 
      WHERE OWNER LIKE '%&p_username%';
   LOOP
         FETCH NAME INTO DDL_WORD;
         EXIT WHEN NAME%NOTFOUND;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE "' || DDL_WORD || '" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
         :g_output := :g_output || ' ' || DDL_WORD;
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE NAME;
END;
/
PRINT g_output
```

Comment: Everything in the data-dictionary is upper-case. You will need to have  `owner like '%' || upper(p_username) || '%'`. Do you really have one table per user?

Comment: I'm entering a username that has 14 tables.  I created them myself and the tables have data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to specify the owner for the table in the `DROP` statement:

```
ACCEPT p_username PROMPT 'Enter Username : '
ACCEPT p_password PROMPT 'Enter New Password for Username : '
VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(4000)
DECLARE
   CURSOR NAME IS SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES 
      WHERE OWNER LIKE '%&p_username%';
   DDL_DROP VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   FOR TNAME IN NAME
   LOOP
       BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE' || ' ' || TNAME.OWNER || '.' || TNAME.TABLE_NAME;
         :g_output := :g_output || ' ' || TNAME.OWNER || '.' || TNAME.TABLE_NAME;
       END;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
PRINT g_output
```

Comment: This one works but sometimes when I run the script, it gives a new error ORA-25153: Temporary Tablespace is Empty

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.

You could try with () like this

```
BEGIN

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (code_text);

END;
```

You could try

```
 c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR 'SELECT * FROM table';
  CLOSE c;
END;
```

Comment: DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 9
Still the same error.